# calling an AJAX method from an ASP.NET MVC 2 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to know how to use Ajax in MVC2. I created an empty project in Visual Studio and added a home controller under Controllers/Home/HomeController.cs with the following code

How do I use AJAX to call the AjaxTest method on the HomeController when the button is clicked and display that text instead?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult AjaxTest()
    {
        return Json("Whoever answers this rocks!");
    }
}
```

I added a view under Views/Home/Index.cs with the following code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sayHello() {
            alert("hello stackoverflow :)")
        }
    </script>

    <div>
        Hello
        <button onclick="sayHello();"> Click Me! </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sayHello() {
        $.get('/Home/AjaxTest', function(data) { alert(data) });
    }
</script>
```

Remember to include jQuery in head section of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also include jQuery in scripts folder of your project. jQuery is a part of ASP.NET MVC framework files.

EDIT:

Change your action to

```
public ActionResult AjaxTest()
{
    return Json("Whoever answers this rocks!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

By default, using Json with get results in "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet." error.

Comment: I put a break point on the controller method and it was being called, there was just no result. I used the overloaded method with the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet and it worked fine :) Thanks for the help @LukLed

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the `<button>` element submits the form by default, which may cause unintended effects on your AJAX calls. Consider `<input type="button" value="Click Me" />` or returning `false` in your `sayHello()` function.